# Get data from textfield inside repeater which is inside a form view

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, objectdatasource, formview

i want to get the value of the textboxes inside the repeater which is inside a form view all binded to object datasource .

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
  DataKeyNames="Id" EnableViewState="False"
  OnPageIndexChanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging" 
  onitemupdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" 
  OnItemUpdating="FormView1_ItemUpdating" ondatabound="FormView1_DataBound"> 
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProdName"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ManufacturerProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"   DataSource='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Distributors") %>'>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ontextchanged="onTextChanged" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FobCost")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PricingsheetWarehouses") %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ontextchanged="onTextChanged" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DeliveredCost")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

i get **txtProdName** as this

```
TextBox t=FormView1.FindControl("txtProdname")as textBox;
```

but i cannot use it to get **textboxes** inside the repeater its giving me null 
any help ??

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the textbox inside of the repeater itself, just how you're doing it with the `FormView1`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  Repeater repeater1=FormView1.FindControl("Repeater1")as Repeater;

protected void RptrSupplier_ItemDataBound(Objectsender,System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // Only process items (not footers or headers) 
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
          TextBox t = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
          t.ID = ((MyType)e.Item.DataItem).ID.ToString(); //you should cast to the type of your object
          t.TextChanged += txt1_TextChanged;
     }
}

protected void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    var tempobject = MyCollection.Where(C => C.ID == t.ID).Single();  
    tempobject.Prop = t.Text;
}
```

Comment: In which event do put this code? first statement must be inside `FormView` binding event and the second inside the `repeater` binding event.

Comment: check my update and add `AutoPostBack="true"` to your text box. make sure you don't rebind your `FormView` while postback your page.

Comment: the thing is that this repeater is binded to a collection of objects and i don't know number of textboxes it will generate,so in TextChanges i can see the text is changing but how can i update my object

Comment: you have to identify your `TextBox` by set its ID with a unique value that should be a property of your object then using `Linq` you can get the object that you will update. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive search to find the control no matter how deep it goes:

```
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string id)
    {
        if (control == null) return null;
        Control ctrl = control.FindControl(id);
        if (ctrl == null)
        {
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                ctrl = FindControlRecursive(child, id);
                if (ctrl != null) break;
            }
        }
        return ctrl;
    }
```

Comment: thnx i try this i find the control textbox but its giving me the old value not the one edited ...